# Multi-threading active wait loops forever

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc

I have experienced something weird that might be a bug in g++ because I didn't reproduce the bug with vc++ thanks to rextester.com

Here is my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

bool cond;

void fct1()
{

    std::cout << "fct1 hello" << std::endl;

    while(!cond)
    {
        //std::cout << "fct1 wait cond" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "fct1 ok" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    cond = false;
    std::thread t(fct1);

    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";

    usleep(100); // some work
    cond = true;
    std::cout << "waiting" << std::endl;
    t.join();

    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

The "usleep" is to let time to the thread to reach the "while" statement before "cond" is set to true. So sometimes, in function of the load of the CPU, this works, but often it does not.
What I get is:

```
Hello, world!
fct1 hello
waiting
```

and a SIGKILL from the rextester.com server because it runs forever.

But, what is funny, it's with the line

```
std::cout << "fct1 wait cond" << std::endl;
```

Then you get something like that:

```
Hello, world!
fct1 hello
fct1 wait cond
fct1 wait cond
fct1 wait cond
...
fct1 wait cond
fct1 wait cond
fct1 wait cond
fct1 wait cond
fct1 wait cond
waiting
fct1 ok
end
```

So my questions are:
Why it does not work when the while statement does nothing?
Is a condition_variable unavoidable?

As I said I also tried with

```
#include <windows.h>
...
Sleep(100);
```

and it worked.

It does not work neither for gcc with

```
while(!cond);
while(!cond) continue;
```

Thank you

Comment: Accessing a variable from multiple threads without synchronization is undefined behavior. Try it with an [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) instead.

Comment: "perceptively forever" loops code can be optimized out. at very least `cond` must be `volatile` to avoid optimization, in fact it should be atomic to be read properly. What you considered proper behaviour, is actually implementation's quirks.

Comment: "Why it does not work when the while statement does nothing?"  why do you think spin testing a flag in a while loop is doing nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said Swift, by just adding a volatile property to the cond variable makes it work with g++.  So it really seems that gcc makes a not wanted optimisation by noting the non synchronisation of the thread with the main thread.

So using a std::atomic variable shall solve this kind of problem. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/atomic/

Thanks to the prompt and right comments.

Comment: Please note, that without `pause` instruction inside the busy loop, it will work bad on x86 with hyper threads.